# How do I generate random strings in python?

Tags: python, random

I was wondering how you generate random strings in Python as opposed to random int's? How would I get around this?

I recently tried to make a random string generator using `random.randint()` and using `if` statements to print different results. When this threw an error I was wondering if there where any other ways of doing it.

Comment: Use a library called faker

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips like starting with your own research. If I just google `python generate random string`, I get useful results.